# vcast media manager huge log files: safe to delete?

Tags: internal-storage, verizon

#### Device Info

- **Phone:** Samsung Galaxy S7
- **Carrier:** Verizon Wireless

#### My issue

My phone is low on available space, so I wanted to delete some things. I noticed that the path `Android/data/com.vcast.mediamanager/files/instabug/logs` is taking up 1.47 GiB of just .txt log files! What is generating these, and is it safe to delete them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Instabug](https://instabug.com/) is an app component for bug- crash- and app performance-monitoring.

Therefore it should be safe to delete this file.

I would also send a bug report to Verizon as `com.vcast.mediamanager` is their
[Verizon Cloud](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vcast.mediamanager) app. May be they forgot to decrease the logging verboseness which leads to such a big log file.